# How to make custom layout in Amazon webstore platform?

Tags: html, e-commerce, amazonsellercentral

I am facing some problem with creating custom layout in Amazon webstore. I actually want to create a 3 column layout but the default templates not support that. I already asked their support team but they didn't provided me the solution of what I want.

They told me that I can make a layout using HTML widget, but with HTML widget I can only place html codes there, where I want to restructure the whole layout and a HTML widget can only be placed only on their defined widget slot. I can't insert other widgets in HTML widget. Does anyone have any idea about that ?

Please click the link to see the image which I want to create. My site is http://www.cruzerlite.com/ and I like to build structure like http://store.mybat.com/

www.diit.info/layout.jpg

Please let me know if you have any confusion regarding this question and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try to download one and reverse engineer it.